# Back elements appear in 3D Earth model usind d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geo

I am trying to make a 3D Earth model (geoOrthographic projection). The problem happens when trying to add new pathes to the spehere.

Here's the sphere before adding the new pathes (back elements are hidden)
[image: before adding colored pathes]

And here's how it looks like after drawing the colored pathes (back elements appears)
[image: after adding colored pathes]

Here's the function used to draw the pathes:

```
function drawPath(drawingPoints, color) {
    let svg = d3.select("svg");

    // Create a line generator using the projection
    let lineGenerator = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return projection([d[0], d[1]])[0]; })
        .y(function (d) { return projection([d[0], d[1]])[1]; });

    // Generate path data using the line generator
    let pathData = lineGenerator(drawingPoints);

    // Append a path element to the svg with the path data
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "coloredClusters")
        .attr("stroke", color)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("fill", color)
        .attr("d", pathData)
}
```

My Update function:

```
function update(newProjection, coloredClusters) {
    if (newProjection) {
        projection = newProjection
    } else {
        // Update projection
        projection = d3['geo' + state.type]()
        projection
            .scale(state.scale)
            .translate([state.translateX, state.translateY])
            .center([state.centerLon, state.centerLat])
            .rotate([state.rotateLambda, state.rotatePhi, state.rotateGamma])
            .clipAngle(90); // This clips the back elements, hiding them.   
    }

    geoGenerator.projection(projection);

    // Update world map
    let u = d3.select('g.map')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(geojson.features)

    u.enter()
        .append('path')
        .merge(u)
        .attr('d', geoGenerator)
        .on('mouseover', handleMouseover);

    // Update projection center
    let projectedCenter = projection([state.centerLon, state.centerLat]);
    d3.select('.projection-center')
        .attr('cx', projectedCenter[0])
        .attr('cy', projectedCenter[1]);

    // Update graticule
    u = d3.select('.graticule path')
        .datum(graticule())
        .attr('d', geoGenerator);

    if (state.coloredClusters) {
        // Clear the svg
        svg.selectAll(".coloredClusters").remove();

            for (let coloredCluster of Object.entries(state.coloredClusters)) {
                for (let [color, points] of Object.entries(coloredCluster[1])) {

                    // console.log(points)
                    if (Array.isArray(points[0])) {
                        if (Array.isArray(points[0][0])) {
                            if (Array.isArray(points[0][0][0])) {
                                for (let [pointsKey, pointsData] of Object.entries(points)) {
                                    drawingPoints = pointsData[0]
                                    drawPath(drawingPoints, color)
                                }
                            }else{
                                drawingPoints = points[0]
                                drawPath(drawingPoints, color)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
    }

    u.enter()
        .append('path')
        .merge(u)
        .attr('d', geoGenerator);


}
```

If there's is another way to color the pathes without need to add new ones it will be fine.

Tried to make isVisible function that checks the pathes. Also, tried clipAngle(90). Both solutions didn't work for me.
I expext to hide the back elemnts in the sphere with the colored pathes to make it looks like the white sphere.